# Is "von der alle beste" correct expression?

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending

I saw someone say "von der aller beste" finishing her remarks towards someone else.  I know this translates to "from all the best"(meaning what I said is from all my best intentions/wishes maybe?)
But I can't understand why it's "aller" here. If "all" is an adjective, shouldn't it be "allen" because beste is a plural and the adjective should end with -en in case of plural dative after "der"?

Comment: "Alle", like in the headline, or "aller"? Without more context imho nearly unanswerable. There might be syllables lost or words omitted. It might be a dialect or personal habit involved. If it was an answer, what was the question?

Comment: The one who said it is a Korean learning German (may have used German before). So it sure is not a dialect. :) When I said that I learned "von der Allerbesten" is the right expression, she agreed and thanked me for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase *von der aller beste* isn't proper German. You may have heard

> von der Allerbesten

*Der/die/das Allerbeste* is a noun made from a super-superlative of the adjective *gut*. You can use this super-superlative with almost any adjective.

> gut – besser – am besten – am allerbesten
>
> neu – neuer – am neuesten – am allerneuesten
>
> blau – blauer – am blauesten – am allerblauesten

You may also hear people adding more *aller*:

> Ich hab' dich am allerallerallerliebsten.

That sounds very childish and may be used for effect.

Comment: Ah I see. Danke schön.